# Nextjs server actions - how to grab custom params set in middleware?

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13

I have `middleware.ts` intercepting every request and authenticating users, but there is data from our database I'd like to pass in these requests where users are authenticated.

I have a server action that looks like this:

```
export async function getProjectsByUser(): Promise<PrismaProject[]> {
  const user = await getUser()
  const projects = await prisma.project.findMany({
    where: {
      user_id: user.id,
    },
    include: {
      Document: true,
      Conversation: {
        include: {
          Message: true,  
        },
      },
    },
  });

  return projects
}
```

Notice the first line in the function grabs the user. I'd rather grab this from the middleware, if possible, but I'm not sure how to reference this. Is there a best practice?

Comment: Keep in mind that Prisma isn't compatible with the Edge runtime on which the middleware is typically running on. That means if your `getUser` is querying this data from the database you cannot perform the same logic in the middleware using Prisma. If, however, `getUser` works differently, such as reading a cookie and parsing the JWT or similar, you can always attach the data to the headers as a custom header and then read them within your server action.

Comment: Yes, I struggled with that and the lack of next documentation explicitly addressing this problem for days. I get around this by having the mdidleware make a request to a custom back-end endpoint which runs the function I've referenced.

Comment: I see. This works but technically it can slow down all requests as they don't run on Edge anymore. In many cases it's not noticeable or not relevant, so if you ever have the feeling things may be slow, remember to benchmark first before attempting some unconventional solutions. But I can confirm that fetching your own endpoint is a very common workaround for Edge limitations.

Comment: Does the newest version of prisma support edge? Also, if running on a non-vercel hosted environment (like GCP), is running edge even possible?

Comment: As far as I understand Prisma will never be able to run on Edge due to the overhead of the Rust-based query engine.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes i think you're right, but there is some prisma data proxy they debuted https://www.prisma.io/blog/database-access-on-the-edge-8F0t1s1BqOJE

Answer (score 0):

I think you can access the data stored in your middleware in your route controller by attaching it to the `req` object. Middleware can add properties/values to the `req` object and it will make it available to route controller.

```
// middleware.ts
export async function authenticateUser(req, res, next) {
  const user = await getUser(); 
  // mechanism
  req.user = user;
  next();
}
```

And then access the `user` data from the `req` object.

```
export async function getProjectsByUser(req: Request, res: Response) {
  const user = req.user;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try this and will mark as answer if works. Appreciate it

Comment: Just to confirm -- I am using the middleware to send a request to a custom back-end api endpoint (to avoid the edge dependency requirements). Are you saying that my server actions (ie located in `./actions.ts`) are able to accept a request as an argument?

Comment: @jamesdlivesinatree this is also my question. have you found the answer?